# How to use class selector on a jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have my HTML inside a jquery object and want to grab an element by class from that object, I have the following code:

```
var feed = data.post.content;
var $newFeed = $(feed);
var stuff = $newFeed('.ERSIngredients').html();
console.log(stuff);
```

When I print $newFeed itself I can see this div with this class exist, but I'm always getting an error: "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: `var stuff = $('<div />', {html : feed}).find('.ERSIngredients').html();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
var stuff = $newFeed.find('.ERSIngredients').html();
```

In other words, find a descendent of `$newFeed` with the class `ERSINgredients` and then get the html out of that.

Comment: OP asked for an element of the jquery object. This gives a descendant of an element of the object. It's possible this is what they meant though.

Comment: So right now I'm trying to get every p elements using the same method by I'm always getting an empty variable.

`var content = "";
      $newFeed.find("p").each(function(index, element) {   
       content += $(this).html();              
      });`

Print empty, but if I change it to for example $newFeed.find("div") then I will get every div.